# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, pycharm

I'm trying to install tensor flow for PyCharm on my MacBook Pro macOS Catalina version 10.15.4. My version of python is 3.8.1. I tried to install Tensor Flow from the Python Interpreter in PyCharm, but I got the ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none. I thought the issue might have been that I hadn't installed a virtual environment virtualenv, so I made sure I installed the virtual environment, python3 and pip3. Then I made sure I had a 64-bit processor to run Tensor Flow. Right now, it seems like I was able to install tensor flow after typing: 
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
into my terminal. The tensor flow folders appear in my Finder, but when I check the shell and type in "import tensorflow as tf" it doesn't recognize any module by that name. I don't know if I installed tensorflow on my MacBook correctly, and I'm not sure how to uninstall any installs if I did the wrong steps. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to reinstall tensorflow from Pycharm terminal itself.
Also if you do not necessarily need python 3.8 ,
Go ahead with an older version 3.6 or 3.7. You do not need to upgrade python to its latest version. This link is also helpful:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: I thought about downgrading Python, but was worried that downgrading might affect my ability to use libraries like PyFirmata. I'm still new to integrating old and new updates and making sure they don't conflict with each other